# Create a test function for multiple typedefs - C

Tags: c, unit-testing, typedef

I usually like to have a bit more of a head start before I ask a question but I am a bit stuck on how to even start this.

I am tasked with creating a small testing framework in C to use strictly with A LOT of different `typedef struct`s.

Say I have a function that returns `mytype_t`:

```
typedef struct mytype {
    void * data;
} mytype_t;

mytype_t my_type_func(char *p) {
    mytype_t q;
    q->data = p;
    return q;
}
```

Now I want to write a function to make sure everything is working as it should:

```
void CUSTOM_ASSERT(void (*test_func)(char*), mytype_t r){
    mytype_t p = (*test_func);
    if(p->data == r->data){
        puts("Test X Passed");
}
```

Called from `driver.c`:

```
int main(void) {
    mytype_t t;
    t->data = "test";
    char *test = "test";
    CUSTOM_ASSERT(my_type_func(test), t);
}
```

Now this works all well and good for this one type and function but there are over 100 `typedef structs` and functions that take none to 10 parameters plus some parameters can be other `typedefs`. That makes using a `va_list` a little tricky as there are no variadic macros for these types (that I know of).

What is the best way to approach this?  I was trying something like:

```
void CUSTOM_ASSERT(void (*test_func)(...), void *should)
```

But I have no clue as to what return type the function pointer is supposed to be able to cast the 2nd parameter of `CUSTOM_ASSERT`.

Comment: Are your sure that even your single example does what it is supposed to do? I see a few „suspicious“ points, e.g., you do not call ˋmy_type_funcˋ in ˋCUSTOM_ASSERT()ˋ (but in ˋmain()ˋ), or you do not compare the strings (but their address).

Comment: @Matthias I am passing `my_type_func` as a function pointer to `CUSTOM_ASSERT`.  Also this is semi-pseudo code to illustrate the problem I am having, not the actual code.  I am not necessarily looking for a "code" answer either.